# Android items in Listview overlap while scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have in my app Listview with items and use for this item an Adapter that extends BaseAdapter. Text of other items overlaps text in another item while scrolling to the bottom.

Here is the code of layout with Listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentRulesLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentRulesFunctions_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the code of the item for this listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ruleFunction_constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ruleFunction_tvDeviceName"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent = "0.6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Initiaize of the adapter

```
private void initRuleAdapter() {
ruleFunctionAdapter = new RuleFunctionAdapter(deviceWithFunctionalities, 
getActivity());
listView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentRulesFunctions_listView);
listView.setAdapter(ruleFunctionAdapter);
}
```

And custom Adapter:

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    itemView = view;

    final DeviceWithFunctionalities dwf = deviceWithFunctionalities.get(i);

    itemView = (itemView == null) ? inflater.inflate(R.layout.rule_function_item, null): itemView;

    final TextView tvDeviceName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ruleFunction_tvDeviceName);
    tvDeviceName.setText(dwf.getName());

    constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ruleFunction_constraintLayout);

    if(dwf.getFunctionalities() != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dwf.getFunctionalities().size(); j++) {
            final TextView tvFunction = new TextView(itemView.getContext());

            tvFunction.setId(TextView.generateViewId());
            tvFunction.setText(dwf.getFunctionalities().get(j));
            tvFunction.setTextSize(20);
            tvFunction.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            constraintLayout.addView(tvFunction);

            ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
            constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

            constraintSet.connect(tvFunction.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, (j) * 100 + 15);
            constraintSet.connect(tvFunction.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 100);

            constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

            tvFunction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SetRuleFunctionsFragment setRuleFunctionsFragment = new SetRuleFunctionsFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("DeviceName", tvDeviceName.getText().toString());
                    bundle.putString("DeviceFunction", tvFunction.getText().toString());

                    setRuleFunctionsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
                            replace(R.id.content_frame, setRuleFunctionsFragment, setRuleFunctionsFragment.getTag()).
                            addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I tried to use in Listview

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
```

but it didnt help at all

Here is screenshot of the problem:[text in item "test5"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwNjj.png)

Really need help. Thanks!

Comment: "Read value" seems to be one possible text for the TextView which you are adding dynamically in getView(). Where do "turn on", "toggle" and "turn off" come from?

Comment: its all from the database. there is an ArrayList  "deviceWithFunctionalities" with different names and functions of the devices. thats why i add all this data dynamically

Comment: If `(itemView != null)` then the `ConstraintLayout` is likely to have some child Views because it is being reused (you can log the value of `constraintLayout.getChildCount()`). You never remove any child Views, you just keep adding them

Comment: your right. sometimes i have more than 100 child. where should i remove it?

Comment: You should remove all child `View`s from constraintLayout before the if block starting with `if(dwf.getFunctionalities() != null) `. If there are no "functionalities" then I suppose you don't need to show anything. Having said that, maybe you would be better of if you used another "inner" `ListView` instead of dynamically adding and removing `TextViews`

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help :( the first column with names disappeared and the app crashes at the end of the list. I need to do it dynamically cause the count of functions differs from device to device. Sorry for bad english

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - I forgot the one "static" TextView. My bad. You should keep that one. Which of course makes it more complicated - you have to loop through all the child Views and only remove them if they do not have the id "ruleFunction_tvDeviceName".  But if you need to loop through them anyway then you should keep as many of them as necessary for the current row (instead of permanently creating and throwing away Views, that's bad for performance) and only remove the surplus Views. Or you switch to the approach with the one TextView and the ListView. That would be even better for performance

Comment: really thanks for your help! i will try it